# MySQL views performance for alias purposes

Tags: mysql, view, alias, memory-optimized-tables

So I'm working on a Rails project and I have a legacy database, that is used by other applications, hence its structure cannot be modified.
The problem is that table and column names do not follow the Rails conventions. A common solution to that is to create MySQL views that just alias columns properly.

These are dead simple views that just have

```
SELECT old_column_1 AS new_column_1, old_column_2 AS new_column_2 FROM table_name;
```

Some tables are really big, like 22 million rows (2GiB). All the tables are `MYISAM`. Also there's one `MEMORY` table with 2 million rows (~350MiB)

The key question is how much of an overhead do I get with such views and does it in any way impact `ROW LOCK` or `TABLE LOCK` during `INSERT`s or `JOIN`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YMMV.  Views *sometimes* fail to do the same optimizations, leading to slower execution than performing the `SELECT` directly.  Since your case is straight forward, probably you will incur no noticeable overhead.

`INSERTs` through a `VIEW` have limitations; sounds like you won't hit them.  Read the manual.

`JOINs` is a place where the optimizer may drop the ball; suggest you experiment offline with that, before committing to make the change.

Comment: should I test if correct indices are used when joining? or is it something about the locks?